# How to display values from mysql database table into a html page using cherrypy?

Tags: html, css, mysql, python-2.7, cherrypy

**how to to render values from database(mysql) table into my html page using cherrypy?**
Actually what I am trying to do is, I have a html page and I want to display values from database in fields against each label.
I have searched and searched a lot, and what i found is this:

```
@cherrypy.expose
def extract(self):
cur = db.cursor()
    cur.execute('select count(*) from config') 
    res = cur.fetchone() 
    db.commit()
    cur.close() 
    return "<html><body>Hello, you have %d records in your table</body></html>" % res
```

Instead of creating a new page in the `return` statement i want these database values to display in my html page, corresponding to their labels.
**How to do that in python using cherrypy?**

[test.html](https://jsfiddle.net/optimusP/bn5hvms1/) this is the link to my html page where in textboxes against the labels i want to display values from database table.

**How to achieve this?** 
PS: I am a newbie to both python and cherrypy, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use some template engine for rendering any html page on the backend (e.i. python application).
[Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org) *may* be a good choice for this. 
As for db access, you may use some ORM. In Python world one of the most popular is [SQLAlchemy](http://sqlalchemy.org). 
To glue it all together you may use [blueberrypy app generator](http://blueberrypy.readthedocs.io), or [my fork of it](https://github.com/open-craft-guild/blueberrypy). Otherwise, please study [the documentation of cherrypy](http://docs.cherrypy.org).

Answer (score -1):

One solution is using Template engines- jinja2 or mako as explained by @webKnjaZ in comment section.
Second solution is:
Return json data from pyhton function and make ajax call from html page to get the data. And once you have json data in your html , you can parse that data and display it in your html page.